# java difference StdOut vs System.out.println

Tags: java, eclipse, stdout, system.out

I have just started working on java, As i downloaded the eclipse and created a java project. 
Project was working fine, then i imported a class but it's not working due to following lines

```
StdOut.println(p + "  " + q);
```

after searching i have replaced it with

```
System.out.println(p + "  " + q);
```

and same way for input.

I tried importing `system.io.*` didn't worked. then i tried `import StdIn` not worked

As i can feel is that it may be due to different project template/type. and tutorials links will also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Most likely, you are enrolled in a course which is attempting to simplify the course without delving into the complexities of the Java programming language. You can download the individual classes here:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`StdOut` is not a class that comes in the JDK.

Though, [StdOut](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/StdOut.java.html) is commonly used in school projects.

Comment: I also had added the jar file for the said stdout class in my project,

Comment: @HaseebAsif: What IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse juno for java developers 
 i can see the added jar file under referenced libraries

Comment: @HaseebAsif: Try reading [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

Comment: Already accomplished this thing but yet no luck :-(

Comment: It did worked for me when i added the jar file specifically for this project. Before this i was trying to add for all project by going windows -- preferences -- java and adding class variables there

Comment: @HaseebAsif: If you want to include the jar for ALL projects, goto Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Find your default JRE and click edit to add the JARs you want.

Comment: @HaseebAsif: Actually you should probably do it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4911947/716076) way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15239/discussion-between-haseeb-asif-and-doug-ramsey)