# How can I add the ACM library in Ecplise?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I'm in an introductory CS class and Dr.Java has really limited functionality compared to Eclipse.  How can I add the ACM.jar file for use in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following video tutorial, which is about ACM. At the first few minutes, it talks about adding it to eclipse. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoyGznP8Ehk

Or else

[Import Libraries in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962559/import-libraries-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Copy it to the project directory. Right click on the jar - select build path, and click add to build path.

You can now import classes from the jar in your classes.

Comment: do I have to do that for every project I make?

Comment: @abacusasian The way I mentioned, yes. You can also add libraries to all projects by going to windows -> preferences -> Java -> Build Path. User Libraries is what you want. Here's the other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911554/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-include-standard-jar-library-for-all-projects