# Netbeans doesn't recognize import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource?

Tags: java, netbeans, datasource

i am trying to access database with DataSource , for configuring datasource i need to import `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` but the problem is that Netbeans doesn't recognize it , saying that package doesn't exist.

(i installed java jdk v.8 , and i am using Netbeans IDE v8.0.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Download** MySql JDBC Jar file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.mysql/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar.zip) and follow the steps below.

Here are screenshots for you.

- **Add** the JAR file in your Project by Right Click on your Project's Library folder

[image]

- **Add Jar/Folder**, Browse the Jar file and add it.

[image]

- **Import** `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` . Done.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept the answer if your problem is solved, as it will help the future users.

Comment: i did it , i am new to the site , i didn't know about the acceptance , otherwise i would have done it in the first place.

Comment: look , is there any way to use this package so i wouldn't have to import it each time i am gonna use it in a prjoect. i mean like the usual packages that we use ?should i put it in the classpath?

Comment: see this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911554/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-include-standard-jar-library-for-all-projects

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911554/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-include-standard-jar-library-for-all-projects